# How do I change the config_file location of a postgresql database for "service postgresql start"?

Tags: database, postgresql, service

I had a PostgreSQL 9.1 db that I just upgraded to 9.3 using

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_upgrade -b /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin -B /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin -d /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/ -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/ -O "-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf" -o "-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf"
```

following the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/ivanvanderbyl/4222308), unfortunately realizing after that I hadn't looked to closely at the last bit.

After the upgrade (which was successful), I found that instead of the default location of the data directory (in this case **/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main**), the option in the upgrade had now configured all of my PostgreSQL config files to be located at **/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/**.

I've spent a while looking for a way to change this and so far I've found that while `hba_file` and `ident_file` can be easily changed in `postgresql.conf` itself, the `config_file` cannot be set except through the `postgres` command line interface.

I tried using `postgres` with the `-o "-c config_file=/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main"` option but it seems that this just tries to start another instance of the service, separate from what a `service postgresql start` does.

Running `pg_ctl status -D ~/9.3/main/` I get

```
`/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres "-D" "/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main" "-c" "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf"`
```

which I take to mean that `-c... /etc...` is being passed to whatever starts the service. Based on my limited knowledge, I believe this to be `/etc/init.d/postgresql` with the `start` parameter. Looking into that, it seems to reference `/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions` which in turn contains the following towards the top

```
do_ctl_all() {
[ "$1" ] || { echo "Error: invalid command '$1'" >&2; exit 1; }
[ "$2" ] || { echo "Error: invalid version '$2'" >&2; exit 1; }
[ -d "/etc/postgresql/$2" ] || return 0
[ "$(ls /etc/postgresql/$2)" ] || return 0
[ -x "/usr/lib/postgresql/$2/bin/postmaster" ] || return 0
...
```

though I'm not sure if these have any relevance.

What I guess I'm asking is if there is any way to configure the `config_file` variable or customize how the service starts.

Thanks for any help! Sorry for my lack of understanding, I'm trying to learn more!

Comment: This is highly OS/distribution/version dependent, so providing that info is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Copy all your configuration files to `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/`.  Make any adjustments that you want to make as part of the upgrade.  Then you should be able to start the new server using

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.3 main start
```

As you have figured out, the Debian packaging of PostgreSQL requires `postgresql.conf` to be located in that place, because it starts there to figure out where everything else is located, including the data directory and the other configuration files.  Make sure your `postgresql.conf` points to the right places for those.

Next time, use `pg_upgradecluster -m upgrade 9.1 main`, and it will figure all of this out for you automatically.